# Wanted: Resource for documented Cross-Browser differences

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

Where can I get a list of browser differences in the implementation of DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out http://quirksmode.org/

Its been a great help to me.
It also has a wealth of classy javascript tutorials.

cheers, jrh

Answer (score 2):

Okay it's only for Gecko but for Gecko specific references take a look at

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/gecko_dom_reference

Answer (score 2):

i second quirksmode.org. i find it most useful via a google site search.

for example, suppose you want to see the different implementations of events

site:quirksmodes.org events

or if you want to know one browser's counterpart in a different browser, just try the one you know

site:quirksmode.org relatedtarget