# Resources for looking up differences in rendering behavior between web-browsers and browser bugs

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I recently encountered a printing issue in Firefox that eventually turned out to be a problem with the fieldset tag we wrapped the entire page in.  ([Bugzilla: Bug 471015](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471015))  All browsers have their own rendering quirks and issues, but it can be very hard to know what's causing different behaviors.  Sure, you can Google, but that's often taking a shot in the dark about what you think is causing the problem.  It also doesn't stop you from having to sort through multiple complains about the same behavior before you find someone who has the issue your looking for.  Are there any websites out there that let you search for rendering behavior issues by browser version, browser function, css tag, or html tag?

I've seen this SO Question, [Wanted: Resource for documented Cross-Browser differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886947/wanted-resource-for-documented-cross-browser-differences), but I'd like to find something more detailed that includes browser bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html
- http://www.positioniseverything.net/
- http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Main_Page#Bugs
- http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css
- http://www.webdevout.net/
- http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Internet Explorer CSS Bugs](http://haslayout.net/css/)

Comment: @ICode: I don't have resources for them, only found this one. BTW, they're not as buggy as IE. ;)

Comment: I know that, but IE is only ~60% of the market today and dropping.  My example bug that got me thinking about this was a bug I encountered in Firefox.  I'm also looking for more then just css bugs.  I'm looking for some general resources, if they're out there.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @secretformula – That's a whole lot of information to include, I can't copy-paste all those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.quirksmode.org/

Comment: I've seen that site, but it's got limited scope in what it offers.